# Find a specific column values?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a table `event_log`, it has fields `id`, `name`, `event_msg`, and `ip`.

I want to fetch `event_msg` values only, rather than the whole row.

Example Structure:

```
|id | name | event_msg |   ip    |
|===|======|===========|=========|
|1  | jojo | sir       |127.0.0.1|
```

Example query: I want to fetch only `event_msg` values matching `sir` in that column

Answer (score 0):

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck, you can do:

```
EventLog.pluck(:event_msg)
# SELECT event_logs.event_msg FROM event_logs
# => ['msg1', 'msg2']
```